# cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, cryptography

Am trying to install cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl on a server that is not connected to the internet. Have upgraded to the latest version of pip 23.1.

This is Windows Server 2016. Python 3.10

d:\python\software\cp310>pip list
Package        Version

---

cffi           1.15.1
cx-Oracle      8.3.0
DateTime       5.1
pip            23.1
pycparser      2.21
pyodbc         4.0.34
pytz           2022.2.1
setuptools     65.5.0
zope.event     4.5.0
zope.interface 6.0

When I run pip install cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl I get this error
ERROR: cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have reviewed the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ to no avail. It does not mention the wheel version that I could find and only instructs on how to install when connected to the interweb, which does not apply in this instance.

I have used older versions of cryptography with older versions of python. But want to upgrade to 3.10 to take advantage of the 64 bit version of cx_oracle. cryptography is the final package I need! Yikes, what is wrong?

Is there a version of cryptography for cp310? Perhaps that is issue.

Am trying to install cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl on a server that is not connected to the internet. Have upgraded to the latest version of pip 23.1.

This is Windows Server 2016. Python 3.10

d:\python\software\cp310>pip list
Package        Version

---

cffi           1.15.1
cx-Oracle      8.3.0
DateTime       5.1
pip            23.1
pycparser      2.21
pyodbc         4.0.34
pytz           2022.2.1
setuptools     65.5.0
zope.event     4.5.0
zope.interface 6.0

When I run pip install cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl I get this error
ERROR: cryptography-40.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have reviewed the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ to no avail. It does not mention the wheel version that I could find and only instructs on how to install when connected to the interweb, which does not apply in this instance.

I have used older versions of cryptography with older versions of python. But want to upgrade to 3.10 to take advantage of the 64 bit version of cx_oracle. cryptography is the final package I need! Yikes, what is wrong?

Is there a version of cryptography for cp310? Perhaps that is issue.

Bob's your uncle. There it's different.

Comment: That *.whl* is  for ***PyPy* *3.9*** (https://www.pypy.org/download.html). Either install that or try building the package yourself.

Comment: 64-bit cx_Oracle packages are available for older versions of Python, see https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files. But if you upgrade anything, upgrade cx_Oracle to the latest release, now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied. I ended up doing a shake and bake on module versions and landed on 3.9 being the one that let me thread this needle.  Kind of wish cryptography was available for the latest version of Python. What with not having internet access and multiple dependencies that would be automatically satisfied if it was connected, this is a very time consuming process.